# Epson 2200 on OSX

Tags: photoshop, printing, epson

I haven't used my printer in a while. It looks like the print dialogue is a bit different than I am used to. I am using the latest OSX, an Epson 2200, and Photoshop.

I have no problem setting the profile in Photoshop. But when the printer dialogue comes up, it seems to ask for a paper selection, even though I am asking Photoshop to do the colour management. I can set "no colour management", but if I change the paper selection (but not the actual paper used), the print looks different. It seems that there is some colour management done by the printer driver even if you specify "no colour management".

I am wondering what I am doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that there is some colour management done by the printer driver even if you specify "no colour management".

Printing the exact same ink onto different papers will give different results. On the other hand, if you tell the printer you have a different kind of paper in the printer it will alter the inks to match the paper. The reason the prints look different is because the printer is changing the ratio of the inks to match a different type of paper when you *didn't* change the paper.

That is why the printer dialogue is asking what type of paper is loaded - so it can use the appropriate blend of inks for each specific color in order to make the image look the way it should based on the type of paper loaded in the printer. If you tell the printer you have one type of paper in it when you really have another type, you won't get accurate colors.

The different stages in your workflow are like different links in a chain. Photoshop manages color while you are processing and editing using Photoshop. The output from photoshop is in a standard graphics format (JPEG, TIFF, PNG, etc.). The printer driver has to translate what PS sends to it in order to print it as accurately as possible. In order to do that it needs to know what kind of paper is being used so it can adjust the inks to match the paper and give you a print that looks like what came out of PS.

When you select a paper type from an option within PS, it is attempting to access the printer driver and change it for you. That change may or may not be reflected when you subsequently open the printer dialogue (because the printer dialogue may default back to a specific setting when you open it), but if you print the image without subsequently opening the printer dialogue the paper choice selected by PS *should* be applied to the print job.

Comment: I wrote that wrong.  What I meant is that if I change the paper selection in the print dialog, but not the actual paper used, then the print looks different.  I changed that on the original question.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Answer updated, but it is pretty much the same thing. The printer has to adjust the ink blend to match the paper you told it you loaded. If you change the ink blend without changing the paper to match the new ink blend, the colors will change. How much depends on the difference between the two papers and how good each ICC profile for that printer/ink/paper combination is.

Comment: I thought the output profile used in photoshop was for that - eg Epson 2200 Velvet fine art PK.  Then if the printer dialog also modifies output based on paper selection, isn't that double adjustment?  Also, the paper I use is not listed, and I cannot seem to find how to add more paper to select (in the printer dialog.  In Photoshop, no problem).

Comment: It depends. Often the last one changed in either place will override the other. Where did you change your paper choice without actually changing the paper?

Comment: In the printer dialog, in the 'print settings' sub page in the 'media type' drop down list.

Comment: And if I leave that as default, and only change the profile in Photoshop, making it the last change, I get the identical results.